# Value initialization for classes with exclusively inherited constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, value-initialization

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) non-union class types without any user-provided constructors will be zero-initialized before being constructed:

> If T is an non-union class type without any user-provided constructors, then the object is zero-initialized and then the implicitly-declared default constructor is called (unless it's trivial)

I'm not sure what should happen when the c++11 inherited constructors are used since the quote explicitly mentions the **implicitly-declared** default constructor.

Given the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int a;
    A() {}
    A(int i): a(i) {}
};

struct B: public A {
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
    B b { 5 };
    B* p = new (&b) B{ };
    std::cout << b.a << std::endl;
}
```

What is the correct output, 0 or 5? Should a class type exclusively providing inherited constructors be zero-initialized before value-initialization (`B{ }`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is `0` because the default constructor for `B` is implicitly declared.

Note that default, copy & move constructors are not inherited; quoting from *§12.9/3 [class.inhctor]*

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor
>   having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter**, a constructor is implicitly
>   declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same
>   signature in the complete class where the using-declaration appears or the constructor would be a default,
>   copy, or move constructor for that class.

---

Your example is similar to the one listed in N3797, *§12.9/6* (edited for brevity)

```
struct B2 {
  B2(int = 13, int = 42);
};

struct D2 : B2 {
  using B2::B2;
};
```

> The candidate set of inherited constructors in `D2` for `B2` is
>   — `B2(const B2&)`
>   — `B2(B2&&)`
>   — `B2(int = 13, int = 42)`
>   — `B2(int = 13)`
>   — `B2()`
>
> The set of constructors present in `D2` is
>   — `D2()`, implicitly-declared default constructor, not inherited
>   — `D2(const D2&)`, implicitly-declared copy constructor, not inherited
>   — `D2(D2&&)`, implicitly-declared move constructor, not inherited
>   — `D2(int, int)`, implicitly-declared inheriting constructor
>   — `D2(int)`, implicitly-declared inheriting constructor

In your case, the candidate set of inherited constructors in `B` for `A` are

```
A()
A(int)
A(const& A)
A(A&&)
```

and the constructors present in `B` are

```
B() implicitly declared, not inherited
B(int) implicitly declared, inherited
B(const& B) implicitly declared, not inherited
B(B&&) implicitly declared, not inherited
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer to move that last paragraph to the beginning of the answer.